# What is the difference between MASM.exe and ml.exe?

Tags: windows, assembly, masm

When i install **masm assembler**, it asked to install Microsoft visual c++ 2005 express edition. I installed it. Now i can find only **"ml.exe"**. Where is masm.exe?
Even i tried in cmd by typing **masm.exe**, but it didn't work. **Is masm.exe and ml.exe same?**

Comment: IIRC, `ml.exe` is the new name for MASM. I don't know when exactly it was changed but I got bitten by this a while back after not using MASM for some years. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0ksfwcf.aspx

Comment: therefore both are same right?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no masm.exe anymore - it's only `ml.exe` and `ml64.exe`. So you can say they're the same - masm.exe got renamed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is MVC++ a mandatory thing for it to run?

Comment: No, MSVC++ is not required for assembly programming. MASM can be installed separately for non-commercial use: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12654. If you want the full suite, Visual Studio may be required (that includes both 32-bit and 64-bit versions).

Comment: If you already installed VS 2005 Express, you will have everything you can get for free for MASM. I've never installed one of the Express editions, so I don't know if it has `ml64.exe`.

Comment: Other software components from the MSDOS days include programmers work bench, code view (source level debugger with text user interface), quick help, nmake, ... .

Answer (score 9):

`MASM.EXE` was the "Microsoft **M**acro **AS**se**M**bler" as MSDOS-program. `ML.EXE` is the ["Microsoft **M**acro Assembler and **L**inker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/afzk3475.aspx)" as Win32-program. `ML64.EXE` is "[MASM for x64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hb5z4sxd.aspx)". They all can be called "MASM". "MASM32" is commonly used for a SDK named [MASM32](http://www.masm32.com/), e.g. for a tag here ([masm32](/questions/tagged/masm32)).

Comment: Some software bundles for ML.EXE 6.11 include both MASM.EXE and ML.EXE, but MASM.EXE just calls ML.EXE with command line parameters for 5.0 compatability. ML.EXE is a 32 bit program, but it will use a built in dos extender if running in 16 bit real mode (like MSDOS). It can also run in a 32 bit dos console window.

Comment: @rcgldr: MASM.EXE 6.11 is in fact a "Microsoft (R) MASM Compatibility Driver Version 6.11" , runs in MSDOS and calls ML.EXE in Win32. But the MSDOS part ("stub") of ML.EXE  reports in DOSBox: "This program cannot be run in DOS mode".

Comment: To run MASM.EXE / ML.EXE 6.11 on MSDOS, you need the dos extender DOSXNT.EXE, and also you need to set an environment variable for the dos extender: set tnt=-nopspgrow . It's not just ML.EXE, but most of the .EXE files that come with "MASM 6.11". I recall using the 6.11 dot directives like .if .else .endif, with several MSDOS projects, and I think I was running ML.EXE in order to use the dot directives. If you patch / update to 6.14 (maybe 6.12 or later), then it won't run under MSDOS.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Developer Network says:

> ml.exe : Assembles and links one or more assembly-language source files.

ml.exe has 64 bit named ml64.exe and I think they are newer version of masm.exe and I think MASM does not have 64 bit version.

Comment: This is incorrect. MASM 6.11 is the last MASM version that works in MS-DOS and it has **both** `masm.exe` and `ml.exe`.

Comment: @nrz Thank you, I did not see that version. I correct my answer. Thanks again